# Javascript equivalent of Task.Yield() in C#

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a service that can only execute one command at a time. Normally this is fine because users of this service should `await` the service calls and thus only one service call should begin at a time, however I can't guarantee this will always be the case. Instead, the service waits to finish its last call before it begins the next one. This is what I do in C#:

```csharp
static async Task<string> Get(string url, params string[] parameters)
{
    while(!isReady)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

I want to do a similar thing in an unrelated NodeJS project.

My Google-fu failed me. Is there a Javascript equivalent of C#'s `Task.Yield()` that I can `await`?

Comment: That's a bad idea in C#. You'll consume a lot of CPU and put tremendous pressure on the managed threadpool.  Instead, you should use a `SemaphoreSlim`, which has a `WaitAsync` method.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Well in actual fact, looking through the version control revisions I see I discovered this myself 3 months after making this post. I changed it from `await Task.Yield()` to `await Task.Delay(10)`. I assume your solution would be better but honestly just delaying 10ms is enough to not cause any CPU spikes. Not to mention, this is a backend admin app that only myself and one other person use, so it's really not important anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, of course! It's simple. This might not be the best way but it works.

```ts
static async RunCommand(cmd: string, ...params: string[]): Promise<string> {
    while(!this.isReady) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a utility function called wait:

```js
export const wait = (millis = 0) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis))

while(!isReady)
  await wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`queueMicrotask()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask) for that.

```js
queueMicrotask(() => {
    // Code here will only run after the current thread have ended and all
    // queued Promises have run until their next wait point or end.
});
```

In Node.js you can also use [`process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processnexttickcallback-args), which should behave the same as `queueMicrotask` in most cases.

```js
process.nextTick(() => {
    // Deferred code goes here
})
```

Comment: The second link is the same as the first

Comment: Awaiting `new Promise(r => queueMicrotask(r));` is pointless, you may as well `await Promise.resolve()` or `await undefined`.

Comment: You are right. I removed this part of the answer and updated the broken link